# Python Pandas - Flag if timestamp falls between multiple start and end times

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one is a series of timestamps and data and the other contain a start and end time on each row. Lets call these df_series and df_interval respectively.

I'd like to create a new column in df_series and then iterate through each row of df_interval and raise a flag if the df_series falls between the start and end time.

I start by creating an empty column in df_series and then iterating through the rows and applying an np.where function.

For completeness, df_series['ts'] corresponds to timestamps, df_event['start'] corresponds to start times and df_event['end'] corresponds to end times.

```
    df_series['event'] = np.nan
    for index, row in df_event.iterrows():
        df_series['event'] = np.where((df_series['ts'] > row['start']) & (df_series['ts'] < row['end']), 1, 0)
```

However, when I run the above it only returns zero values despite the values of 'ts' falling between the values of 'start' and 'end'. It does not throw any errors but is not behaving as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by taking a different approach.

First, creating an empty dataframe and then iterating through df_events, applying a mask to df_series based on each row and appending the results to this empty dataframe. Then merging the new dataframe with the existing df_series. See example code below.

```
events = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df_events.iterrows():
    mask = (df_series['ts'] >= row['start']) & (df_series['ts'] <= row['end'])
    events = events.append(df_series.loc[mask])
events['event'] = 1
events = events['event']

series_events = df_series.merge(events, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```